# ****ansible.errors.AnsibleError: Unable to find an inventory file, specify one with -i ?****

Tags: python-2.7, ansible-inventory, ansible-api

> ****ansible.errors.AnsibleError: Unable to find an inventory file, specify one with -i ?****

### My script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ansible.playbook
from ansible import callbacks
from ansible import utils
ANSIBLE_HOSTS = 'hosts'
PLAYBOOK = 'sample1.yml'
def deploy():
stats = callbacks.AggregateStats()
playbook_cb = callbacks.PlaybookCallbacks(verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)
inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(ANSIBLE_HOSTS)
runner_cb = callbacks.PlaybookRunnerCallbacks(stats,verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)

pb = ansible.playbook.PlayBook(playbook=PLAYBOOK,
                               callbacks=playbook_cb,
                               runner_callbacks=runner_cb,
                               stats=stats,
                               inventory=inventory,
                               extra_vars={'test': "TEST"})
pb.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   deploy()
```

### sample1.yml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  sudo: no
```

### /etc/ansible/hosts:

```
[localhost]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```